# Flutter - Openweathermap api call error - Passing parameter to api call doesn't work

Tags: flutter, dart, openweathermap

Location class is the responsible for getting the longitude and latitude. 
getData() method from the Loading_screen class is the responsible for calling the api to get weather data. The problem is when I pass the longitude and latitude values to the url of api, it returned error 400. 
Workaround is to hardcode the longitude and latitude and it successfully retrieved api data. I can't figure why passing longitude and latitude values to api call doesn't work

Location

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Location{
  double longitude;
  double latitude;

  Future<void> getCurrentLocation() async{
    try{
      Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low);
      longitude = position.longitude;
      latitude = position.latitude;
      print('Longitude: $longitude \n' +
            'Latitude: $latitude');
    }catch(e){
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Loading_screen class

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:clima/location.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingScreenState createState() => _LoadingScreenState();
}

class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen> {

  var apiKey = 'secret';
  double lat, lon;
  @override
  void initState() {
    getLocation();
  }

  void getData() async{

    var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&${lon}&appid=$apiKey';
    //var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=14.6102473&121.0043158&appid=secret';
    //var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=14.6102473&lon=121.0043158&appid=secret';


    var request = await http.get(url);
    if(request.statusCode == 200){
      String data = request.body.toString();
      var city = jsonDecode(data)['name'];
      var description = jsonDecode(data)['weather'][0]['description'];
      print('Welcome to $city city!');
      print('Weather: $description');
    }else{
      print(request.statusCode);
      print('Latitude is: $lat *** Longitude is: $lon'); // this prints longitude and latitude values 
      print('request $url'); // when I entered the url in postman, I'm getting the same error 400
    }
  }

  void getLocation() async{
    Location location = new Location();
    await location.getCurrentLocation();
    lat = location.latitude;
    lon = location.longitude;
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you print and check what was the url when you passed those fields to create the url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the parameter name `lon` in your url.

Instead of:

```
var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&${lon}&appid=$apiKey';
```

Write:

```
var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=$apiKey';
```

Answer (score 2):

Change that;

```
var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&${lon}&appid=$apiKey';
```

with this;

```
var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=$apiKey';
```